# How to clean and maintain composite sinks?

Tags: sink, cleaning, maintenance, stain

Our kitchen was fitted less than one month ago. Everything runs very smoothly and is still very shiny, but [our composite sink](https://www.howdens.com/kitchens/kitchen-sinks-and-taps/kitchen-sinks/single-bowl-reversible-inset-composite-white-compact-kitchen-sink-snk2148) is staining very quickly. I have read that they should be very simple to maintain and an occasional nylon brush with warm soapy water should make it look as good as new, but I tried it several times now and I see no effect.

Specifically, I am looking for guidance on the following maintenance question:

1. What is the likely source of the stains in the image attached, how to clean and avoid them in the future?
2. Are there any methods or products to avoid with a composite sink e.g. bleach, steal scourers?
3. Can I use boiling water to disinfect?

[image: Stains in the sink]

Comment: What does the sink manufacturer say for this model? There are a lot of "composite" materials out there...

Comment: I've added a link to the model that I could find on the quote. The documentation is quite basic and I think quite contradictory. It says "scratch resistant", but at the same time "avoid abrasive cloths". It permits the use of nylon scratch pads and stain remover so I give those a go. Nothing about temperature resistance.

Comment: Hmm. I'd be halfway inclined to plug the drain and add tea and rotgut red wine to stand overnight, and then say - here's the new sink color! Meanwhile, I just use boring "cheap" easily cleaned stainless steel for a kitchen sink... Some of the staining might indicate iron or manganese in your water supply. Not very impressed with the makers of your new sink.

Comment: I took a look at that link. It's pretty vague. I'd contact the mfgr by phone, email or chat and ask them about it. It's possible that your sink has defects in the finish that's allowing this staining. It's also possible that it's just rubbish. In either case, since it's only a month old and it's got a 10-year warranty, I'd go to the manufacturer. It may be a pain to have the sink replaced, but better that than living with it.